# Workaround for SonarError for 'Named function expressions should not be used'

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, settimeout

```
const objTimeout = setTimeout(
    function firePostMessagesToSubTab() {
    if (boolRemoved) {
        clearTimeout(objTimeout);
    } else {
        soneAsyncMethod.then(function () {
            setTimeout(firePostMessagesToSubTab, 1000);
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

I have written a recursive setTimeout but our sonar filter is throwing error as

> 'Named function expressions should not be used'.

Is there a workaround for this? There is no way that the sonar rule can be removed (Clients...). Also I have deliberately used setTimeOut and not setInterval because setInterval does not wait for the method to get finished.

Comment: Declare the function. Then use `const objTimeout = setTimeout(firePostMessagesToSubTab, 1000);`

Comment: But how will that fire it recursively? and also clearTimeout when the boolRemoved is met?

Comment: I'm not changing the code's logic; I'm just moving the function declaration outside the `setTimeout` call. First, declare `var objTimeout;`. Next, declare the function. Finally, do `objTimeout = setTimeout(firePostMessagesToSubTab, 1000);`

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0uqoxc3p/

Comment: Yes understood, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function firePostMessagesToSubTab() {
```

Here `firePostMessagesToSubTab` is the name of the function. Basically the code analysis tool is suggesting that you use an anonymous function or declare the function separately from the setTimeout invocation.

Change your code to following and it should pass the rule

```
function firePostMessagesToSubTab() {
    if (boolRemoved) {
        clearTimeout(objTimeout);
    } else {
        soneAsyncMethod.then(function () {
            setTimeout(firePostMessagesToSubTab, 1000);
        });
    }
}
const objTimeout = setTimeout(firePostMessagesToSubTab, 1000);
```

Comment: firePostMessagesToSubTab should again recall the same function, according to this it might throw error.

Comment: Declared objTimeout at top, `let objTimeout`